# Extremely slow built-in AES encryption with Java

Tags: java, performance, encryption, aes

I have a lot of very small data (19 Bytes) that need to be encrypted and sent
to a remote server via tcp in encrypted format. I am using the code below to
do this.

```
package aesclient;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESClient {
    static byte[] plaintext = new byte[] {0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1337); // connecting to server on localhost
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            String s_key = "Random09" + "Random09"; // 16 Byte = 128 Bit Key
            byte[] b_key = s_key.getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec sKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(b_key, "AES");
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
            byte[] IV = new byte[16]; // initialization vector
            int num = 10000;
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
                random.nextBytes(IV);
                IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKeySpec, ivSpec);
                byte[] msg = new byte[16 + 32];
                System.arraycopy(IV, 0, msg, 0, IV.length);
                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
                System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, msg, IV.length, encrypted.length);
                outputStream.write(msg);
                outputStream.flush();      
            }
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = end - start;
            double drate = ((double)plaintext.length*(double)num)/((double)duration/1000000000);
            System.out.println("Verschlüsselung:\n" + num + " mal 19 Bytes in " + ((double)duration/1000000000) + " s\nData Rate = " + drate/1000.0 + " kBytes/s");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } 
}
```

I am wondering why it is extremely slow. I get an output like this:

```
Verschlüsselung:
10000 mal 19 Bytes in 2.566016627 s
Data Rate = 74.04472675694785 kBytes/s
```

which means I have a data rate of 74 kByte/s of the original (unencrypted)
data. The data rate only increases negligibly if I omit sending over TCP
(then it's about 100kByte/s). I have read about data rates that are around
20MByte/s or even higher. I have a laptop with Windows 10 and i5 processor.
I would be grateful for any help. As I said, I just need to transfer a lot
of small data packets (19 Byte) encrypted.

Comment: Why don't you use a buffered stream? Why do yoy flush in every iteration? Flush at the end and use a buffered stream to improve performance. Also read the comment in the accepted answer.

Comment: The code I have shown is only an illustration of my problem. In truth, I have to forcibly call the flush () command each time because I can not say how long I have to wait for the next 19 bytes I want to send to the server. My application is just a "translator" that encrypts and sends data to the server. The data is very small (19 bytes), it can be infinitely many and it is unknown in advance, in which intervals they arrive at me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SecureRandom` is slow even in PRNG mode and can even block when not enough entropy is available.

I recommend sourcing the random IV once and incrementing it between iterations similar to CTR mode. Or just use CTR mode.

```
public class Test {
    static byte[] plaintext = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x51,
            0x52, 0x53 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/PKCS5PADDING");
            String s_key = "Random09" + "Random09"; // 16 Byte = 128 Bit Key
            byte[] b_key = s_key.getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec sKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(b_key, "AES");
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            byte[] IV = new byte[16]; // initialization vector
            random.nextBytes(IV);
            int num = 10000;
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
                IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKeySpec, ivSpec);
                byte[] msg = new byte[16 + 32];
                System.arraycopy(IV, 0, msg, 0, IV.length);
                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
                System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, msg, IV.length, encrypted.length);
                increment(IV);
            }
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = end - start;
            double drate = ((double) plaintext.length * (double) num) / ((double) duration / 1000000000);
            System.out.println("Verschlüsselung:\n" + num + " mal 19 Bytes in " + ((double) duration / 1000000000) + " s\nData Rate = " + drate
                    / 1000.0 + " kBytes/s");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void increment(byte[] iv) {
        for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
            if (++iv[i] != 0)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Verschlüsselung:
10000 mal 19 Bytes in 0.0331898 s
Data Rate = 5724.650344382912 kBytes/s
```

At least 30 times faster on my machine.

Comment: It seems you are the new gold standard regarding "performance" questions. Not all jealous I am.

Comment: @rustyx Many thanks for your response. To check your statement, I simply commented out the line `random.nextBytes (IV)` and always encrypted with the same initialization vector. It turned out that the encryption is 5 times faster. My real concern is to be able to provide two functions, one for encryption and one for decryption, which should then be used in a .dll in a LabVIEW environment. The LabVIEW environment is the server I'm trying to transfer data to. So I want to write the .dll in C#. If I use AES with CTR in Java now, then I have to think about how to program the counterpart in C#.

Comment: Incrementing the IV is a very good idea. Thank you. That is all I need.

Comment: Do not I have to create a new object of type IvParameterSpec if the IV changes?

Comment: This doesn't look secured. CBC IV must be unpredictable at the time of encryption. @LukasNothhelfer be careful. Since IV is not a secret, an attacker can know the IV of a message easily and since you are incrementing, an attacker can predict all subsequent IVs. Also why don't you use an authenticated encryption mode (like GCM) BTW? And why is the key hard coded? Why the key is in a `String`? Why are you not using a key derivation function like PBKDF2 to convert a this word "Random09" into a key? Not secured at all.

Comment: GCM/CTR mode uses a 12 byte fixed "nonce", the remaining 4 bytes are the counter, starting from 1. So this solution is slightly more secure in fact, since the counter starting value is also random.

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu Why is it a problem if the attacker can predict the IV as long as he doesn't know the key. This is just an example. The key will not be hardcoded.

Comment: @LukasNothhelfer refer to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation. CBC and CTR are not same. When developing a software, stick to what the algorithm or mode specifications require. It's recommended that you don't invent your own solution for a software because these modes, algorithms and their requirements have been reviewed and tested by hundreds of people for many many years. Custom made solutions have in the past found to be broken. BTW why don't you use multi threads to speed up the process. Try figure out alternatives rather than compromising security

Comment: @LukasNothhelfer on top of the above comments, if you still think you cannot use `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()`, at least try using `SHA1PRNG`. I think this is non-blocking as it uses SHA-1 on an incrementing sequence instead of blocking for entropy from the underlying OS. It is not as secured, but still better than a plain incrementing sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed `SecureRandom` as used is notorious slow, and even blocking. It is the bottle neck here.
So encrypt a larger buffer, several messages, when feasible.

Otherwise there are still some minor things to consider:

```
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        int bufSize = Math.min(socket.getSendBufferSize(), 1024);
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(sock, bufSize);

        byte[] b_key = s_key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

        byte[] msg = new byte[16 + 32];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            random.nextBytes(IV);
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKeySpec, ivSpec);
            System.arraycopy(IV, 0, msg, 0, IV.length);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
            System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, msg, IV.length, encrypted.length);
            outputStream.write(msg);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
```

There are better ways to deal with byte arrays using an overloaded [doFinal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html).
Then the code is cleaned up, removes `arraycopy` here.

Also I would use try-with-resources for closing sockets and other things on irregularities (exceptions, timeouts).

Comment: Tank you for your answer. Your solution is good, but the number of small data (19 bytes) is infinite and not limited. That's why I can not allocate anything in advance. The typical sockets procedure was omitted in this example so as not to inflate the code.

Comment: This is the correct answer. But arraycopy to my understanding is blazingly fast. It uses memcpy to copy the memory chunk.

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu that was a style issue: an overloaded `doFinal` can do all that is done now (also doing internally a memcopy). The advantage is only that the code is smaller, less error prone = more readable. Hence I did not rewrite that part; is up to the OP, as the code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need security or do you need AES? A block cipher sounds like a bad choice as it inflates you data by from 19 to 48 bytes.

The accepted answer gives you two recommendations, where one is AFAIK a security disaster: Incrementing the counter does hardly anything useful in [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)).

The other recommendation, namely using the counter mode is AFAIK fine. It effectively turns a block cipher into a stream cipher and allows you to send only 16+19 bytes. Most probably, you can use fewer than 16 bytes for the counter.

Another inefficiency comes from the cipher initialization in a loop. IIRC it costs more than the encryption of your two blocks.

> The data is very small (19 bytes), it can be infinitely many and it is unknown in advance, in which intervals they arrive at me.

Nonetheless, you can process it more efficiently. Read all bytes you get at once. When it's just 19 bytes, then encrypt and send it. In case, it's less, continue reading. In case, it's more, then encrypt it all and send. This way you can be more efficient... and even a dead slow `SecureRandom` can't be a problem as you need just one IV for a large block (the longer your processing took, the more data you get at once).

Comment: I need security. I get packages of size 19 byte that I have to encrypt and send to the server.
The maximum data rate of the 19 byte packages is 1 MBit/s. There is a 1000TX Ethernet connection to the server, so there should not be a bottleneck here. It is ok if the messages grow larger as a result of the encryption, as long as this is feasible with a data rate of 1 MBit/s. Why is it a problem for any message to simply increment the IV? As far as I know, the IV does not have to be kept secret.

Comment: @LukasNothhelfer The IV doesn't need to be secret, but it has to be unpredictable. Look at the image in my link what happens with it: It just gets xored to the data. So when you data gets just decremented, then this changes cancels with the nonce increment and you send the same encrypted data twice. Assuming the attacker knows your encryption schema, then they know exactly what happened. If you consider this improbable, then you're relying on the unpredictability of your data rather than on crypto.

Comment: My data consists of 4 byte header, 12 byte user data and 7 byte time stamp. It is very unlikely that IV and data compensate each other if only the IV is counted up. The pure counting of the IV is probably not recommended, so I'll go with @SaptarshiBasu proposal and use SHA1PRNG. Thank you for your help